# JavaScript Trying to read object giving me undefined on console

Tags: javascript

I am trying to read some data what I have.

My console is showing that it looks like this:

```
    {
    "calls":"0",
    "ids":[
        {
            "id":"5117-9e39-7afd-46b3-a066-14e4-3433-871f",
            "feat":{
                "dates":{
                    "exp":"2018-10-02"
                },
                "read":[
                    {
                        "name":"Joe"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So I'm trying to console.log so it gives me the name.

I've done this:

```
console.info(data.ids.read.name)
```

This is returning **undefined**.

How can I get it to return the name?

Comment: Hi, can you please share the following `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))`

Comment: please update your formate . i think your formate is not valid

Comment: can we see the whole object ? may be you can stringify and paste it over here

Comment: Still having issues. Here is the object: {
 "calls":"0",
 "ids":[
  {
   "id":"51",
   "feat":{
    "dates":{
     "exp":"2018-10-02"
    },
    "read":[
     {
      "name":"Joe"
     },
    ],
   }
  }
 ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment showing the whole of `data`, you would need to use `data.ids[0].feat.read[0].name` to get the name.

Note that `ids` and `read` hold arrays, hence the need for the `[0]`.

Comment: That's what I thought and tried but it says feat is undefined

Answer (score 0):

based on what you describe I think your problem is caused by you logging an object and logging a particular member of the object.

The console.log statement will give you a preview that you can expand, the preview shows the object as it is when you log it. It will sometimes give you an option to expand it and that expanded view will show the object as it is now.

When you log a primitive value or get a non expandable preview then you'll always see the object as it is when you log it.

Nikhil's suggestion to log the JSON string from the object is a good tip since you will log the object as is when you log it (string is primitive and won't give you an expand option). You could also use console.table.

Below you can see the behavior and difference of preview and expanded (you can run it in the browser's console):

```
var arr = [];
console.log('empty array?',arr);//previews to [] but expands to array with one object
console.log('undefined wont change',arr[0])//logs undefined because arr is still empty
arr.push({name:'ben'});//mutate array to add one item
```

You may be logging something that is mutated later by a resolving promise or from a callback.